# Correct Excel Macro to Save A Copy Excel File as TXT or CSV

Tags: vba, excel

So I have this *home-made* Excel Macro Template.

[image]

The task of the macro code that I inserted in my xlsm file is to Save a copy in the same folder with a different format. That format is .txt (see image below)

[image]

The expected result of the macro (after saving) should be the same with the excel file (visually) but this time it is in a .txt format.

Unfortunately, that didn't happened. It generates a different txt file and it contains unreadable alpha numeric characters, here's an example of the generated txt file.

```
    ¬TËNÃ0 ¼#ñ ‘¯(vá€ jÚ  #   °µ· ©c[^SÚ¿g“–
P  ö '±wfvìq 8o\1ÃD6øJœËž(Ðë`¬ŸTâõå¾¼  eð \ðX‰ ’  NOú/‹ˆTpµ§JÔ9Çk¥H×Ø É ÑóÌ8¤ 2 ¦‰Š §0AuÑë]* |FŸËÜbˆAÿ Çðîrq7çßK%#ëEq³\×RU btVCf¡jæ l¨ã±Õ(g#xJá
u j#XBG{Ð~J.Wr%WvŒTÛHgÜÓ †vf»ÜUÝ#ûœ¬Áâ  R~€†›Rs§>BšŽB˜ÊÝ «žq®ÑIª ³l@§pçaä ý ë¿ î`ê*IuÃù (  ³´Ü ýÞð JŠ   Át` “m'Ýû  ™    ªîy¸„ f !å…C:r·KÐ}Ì5$4Ï9q Ž.à;ö. ¼]  H ¼„ÿwá+mu   S¶¸ŽÃ¦Ã¶fäÔ l;¶×‚A³ [u×Ðà   ÿÿ  PK          ! µU0#ô   L       _rels/.rels ¢  (
```

Here's my macro code:

```
Sub SaveMe()
    Dim FName As Range
    Dim firstDate As String
    Dim firstTime As String
    Dim answer As Integer

    firstDate = Format(Date, "mmddyyyy")
    firstTime = Format(Now, "hhmmssAM/PM")

    Set FName = Range("H5")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "QB JE " & FName & " " & firstDate & " " & firstTime & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

I was wondering if anyone could take a look at my code and help to point out whats wrong.

Comment: Your saving command works fine for me. Could you try     `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="xxxxx.csv",         FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False` instead? I know you want a tab delimited file but maybe this can help debug.

Comment: yep! i think you're correct @nhee.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the SaveAs Not the SaveCopyAs.

Fileformat xlText or xlTextMSDOS

You can two step the process.  Save a copy, then open it, and save it as a text file.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "QB JE " & FName & " " & firstDate & " " & firstTime & ".xlsx"

Workbooks.Open (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "QB JE " & FName & " " & firstDate & " " & firstTime & ".xlsx")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "QB JE " & FName & " " & firstDate & " " & firstTime & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx

Comment: Hi @MatthewD! Thanks for your code. Actually, I need the macro SaveCopyAs. Though your code above works perfectly BUT is there a way if you could modify that to SaveCopyAs so it will save another copy in the same folder in TXT file? I've tried (just) changing your code 'SaveAs' to 'SaveCopyAs' but i encountered an error saying Named argument not found.

Comment: It doesn't look like savecopyas has a fileformat.  You could savecopyas, then open the copy and saveas to the text file.

Comment: Now I understand why its giving me errors. is there a way to automate that that runs in split seconds?

Comment: You can use it as it is.  It's speed will depend on the size of the workbook and computer hardware.

Answer (score 0):

See from my post here. [Excel VBA Export To Text File with Fixed Column Width + Specified Row and Columns Only + Transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620537/excel-vba-export-to-text-file-with-fixed-column-width-specified-row-and-column/31621007#31621007)

Loop all rows and all cells. Send each value to a padspace function. Build the string from for each cells value with spaces padded after the cell value.

You will have to add a reference to you workbook. In the VBA IDE go to the tools pull down menu and select references. Then scroll down and select "Microsoft Scripting Runtime". Then hit OK.

Adjust the pad space function call argument to a number that fits the data that you have in your spreadsheet. So you will change the 20 in the line with the padspace call. PadSpace(20, len(cellValue))

This will do all rows and columns.

```
Public Sub MyMacro()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim strRow As String
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ts As TextStream
Dim fs As FileSystemObject

'Create the text file to write to
Set fs = New FileSystemObject
Set ts = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\test.txt", True, False)

Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

'Loop through all the rows.
lRow = 1
Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

    'Clear the string we are building
    strRow = ""

    'Loop through all the columns for the current row.
    lCol = 1
    Do While lCol <= ws.UsedRange.Columns.count
        'Build a string to write out. 
        strRow = strRow & ws.Cells(lRow, lCol) & PadSpace(20, Len(ws.Cells(lRow, lCol)))
        lCol = lCol + 1
    Loop

    'Write the line to the text file
    ts.WriteLine strRow

    lRow = lRow + 1
    ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
Loop

ts.Close: Set ts = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing

End Sub

'This function will take the max number of spaces you want and the length of the string in the cell and return you the string of spaces to pad.
Public Function PadSpace(nMaxSpace As Integer, nNumSpace As Integer) As String
    If nMaxSpace < nNumSpace Then
        PadSpace = ""
    Else
        PadSpace = Space(nMaxSpace - nNumSpace)
    End If
End Function
```